# Use Lens.Family.LensLike' as setter and getter in State computations

Tags: haskell, lenses

I would to use same lens as setter and getter inside stateful computations.
And it seems that GHC is unable to deduce common type for Functor f.

```
import Lens.Family
import Lens.Family.State
import Control.Monad.State

-- | Run computation inside modified state
with :: Functor f => LensLike' f s a -> a -> State s b -> State s b
with lens value comp = do
  value' <- use lens
  lens .= value
  res <- comp
  lens .= value'
  return res
```

So my question is, is it possible to achieve such behavior or should I use separate lenses for setter and getter? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of options here.  First, you could use RankNTypes so that a different Functor instance can be used at each "call site", ensuing you can use the LensLike' as both a getter and a setter:

```
with :: (forall f. Functor f => LensLike' f s a) -> a -> State s b -> State s b
```

Second, and probably better, is to use the `Lens'` type which already is existential -- allowing use as both a getter and a setter.

```
with :: Lens' s a -> a -> State s b -> State s b
```

You have to allow the Functor to vary from "call site" to call site, as choosing a particular Functor is what changes a lens to a getter or a setter.  The Identity Functor is used for setting, the Const functor is used for getting.